# Nested JSON data using MySQL and PHP for AngularJs | ng-options

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

Could anyone please tell me how to create the following nested JSON data using MySQL and PHP in codeigniter.

I want my data in the given format.

```
$data =  {
    'India': {
        'Andhra Pradesh': ['Vijayawada', 'Guntur', 'Nellore', 'Kadapa'],
        'Madhya Pradesh': ['Hyderabad', 'Warangal', 'Karimnagar'],
    },
    'USA': {
        'San Francisco': ['SOMA', 'Richmond', 'Sunset'],
        'Los Angeles': ['Burbank', 'Hollywood']
    },
    'Australia': {
        'New South Wales': ['Sydney', 'Orange', 'Broken Hill'],
        'Victoria': ['Benalla', 'Melbourne']
    }
};
```

My Model code is below:

```
public function getAll()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT
        `country`.`countryName`
        , `states`.`name` AS `stateName`
        , `cities`.`cityName`
        FROM
        `tablename`.`states`
        INNER JOIN `tablename`.`country` 
            ON (`states`.`country_ID` = `country`.`ID`)
        INNER JOIN `tablename`.`cities` 
            ON (`cities`.`state_id` = `states`.`ID`);");

        return $query->result();

    }
```

And Controller code is given below :

```
public function getAllData()
{
    //get All details
    $this->load->model('Shiksha_model','locations');
    $data = $this->locations->getAll();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

So I am gating the ouput as given below :

```
[
  {
    "countryName": "INDIA",
    "stateName": "West-Bengal",
    "cityName": "Kolkata"
  },
  {
    "countryName": "INDIA",
    "stateName": "Bihar",
    "cityName": "Purnia"
  }
]
```

Comment: What are the options you need on your drop down select?

Comment: That drop-down part is working fine with the desired JSON data. But I am not able to build/echo out that nested JSON formated data anyhow.  I need help to format the data like this  {
                        'India': {
                            'Andhra Pradesh': ['Vijayawada', 'Guntur', 'Nellore', 'Kadapa'],
                            'Madhya Pradesh': ['Hyderabad', 'Warangal', 'Karimnagar'],
                        },....   drop-down is not my concern, formatting the json data is my main issue.

Comment: try to use angular-filter ,it will allows you to filter as you desired on front end you can easy access it in the controller as well.https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Comment: Sorry to say, but I think I am unable to make you understand my problem. I have no problem with AngularJs and filtering at all. I just want to echo that JSON data with that specific nested format mentioned at the beginning of my post. Try understand my question first .

Comment: 3 dimensional array is encoded to achieve the JSON data. So you loop through the result and format the result set Like, `array('India'=>array('Andhra Pradesh'=>array(Vijayawada', 'Guntur', 'Nellore', 'Kadapa')))` then do `json_encode`

Comment: Hmm...That's sounds interesting...Could you please edit my code and reply back so I could test it. That will be a big help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through and build what you need:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
  if (!isset($result[$row['countryName']]))
    $result[$row['countryName']] = [];
  if (!isset($result[$row['countryName']][$row['stateName']]))
    $result[$row['countryName']][$row['stateName']] = [];
  $result[$row['countryName']][$row['stateName']][] = $row['cityName'];
}
return json_encode($result);
```

You also can achieve same result with same client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

This is modification I have done in my model and now its working perfectly !
Thank you everyone...

```
 public function getAll()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT
        `country`.`countryName`
        , `states`.`name` AS `stateName`
        , `cities`.`cityName`
        FROM
        `tablename`.`states`
        INNER JOIN `tablename`.`country` 
            ON (`states`.`country_ID` = `country`.`ID`)
        INNER JOIN `tablename`.`cities` 
            ON (`cities`.`state_id` = `states`.`ID`);");

        $data = $query->result_array();

        $result = [];
        foreach ($data as $row) {
          if (!isset($result[$row['countryName']]))
            $result[$row['countryName']] = [];
          if (!isset($result[$row['countryName']][$row['stateName']]))
            $result[$row['countryName']][$row['stateName']] = [];
          $result[$row['countryName']][$row['stateName']][] = $row['cityName'];
        }

        return $result;
    }
```